# List of lists through function in python

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to get a list of lists through this function in python, when I run it I only get back the last list L. How can I edit my code so that each iteration is saved in a common list?
Thank you in advance

```
FB = []
while True:
    given_name = input("Hva er fornavnet ditt? ")
    if given_name == 'done':
        break
    surname = input("Hva er etternavnet ditt? ")
    age = int(input("Hvor gammel er du? "))
    gender = input("Hvilket kjønn har du? ")
    def add_data():
        L = []
        L.append(given_name)
        L.append(surname)
        L.append(age)
        L.append(gender)
        return L
    add_data()
FB.append(add_data())
print(FB)
```

Comment: `FB.append(add_data())` needs to be inside the loop, in place of your current `add_data()` line that just throws away its result.

Comment: You don't need to redefine your function with each loop. That should be outside of the while. Also, at the start of add_data() you erase the old `L` but don't add l to FB until after loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the data outside of the loop, which means you are resetting the list every time inside the while loop with `L=[]`.

You also don't need an additional `add_data()` function and simply use the built in `.append` method to add your list `L` to the main `FB` list.

You can simplify your code like this:

```
FB = []
while True:
    given_name = input("Hva er fornavnet ditt? ")
    if given_name == 'done':
        break
    surname = input("Hva er etternavnet ditt? ")
    age = int(input("Hvor gammel er du? "))
    gender = input("Hvilket kjønn har du? ")

    L = []
    L.append(given_name)
    L.append(surname)
    L.append(age)
    L.append(gender)

    FB.append(L)

print(FB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an OOP approach. Helps get rid of the repeated appends for each attribute:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, gender):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.gender = gender

    def get_list_description(self):
        return [self.name, self.surname, self.age, self.gender]

FB = []
while True:
    given_name = raw_input("Hva er fornavnet ditt? ")
    if given_name == 'done':
        break
    surname = raw_input("Hva er etternavnet ditt? ")
    age = int(raw_input("Hvor gammel er du? "))
    gender = raw_input("Hvilket kjonn har du? ")

    p = Person(given_name, surname, age, gender)
    FB.append(p.get_list_description())

print(FB)
```